# Copy paste with changing paste destination

Tags: excel, vba

Howdy  I have a parts list that I have built a search page for. I need the parts list locked out accept for the Qty which needs changed from the search page. I can find it, display it, display the location and hyperlink to it. I can also of course calculate the new amount but I need it to change the Qty on the Parts List page. I can make a macro that will paste info into a know destination but the destination will change with the search so I need it to paste to the location found in a cell or find the location the info came from on the parts list page and paste the new amount there. Please can you help.

**Search** =1234

**Search Results**
Part# 1234  Qty 4   Removing  -1    Remove from -Parts list, $E$6
                New Qty   3
**Parts list**
Part# 1234         Current Qty 4 (paste new qty here)

Answer (score 0):

Howdy:)I Found an answer if anyone else is looking. Trevor_S on MrExcel sent me a code that used  Sheets("Parts list").Range(Sheets("Search").Range("D3").Value).Value = to find the location on the parts list page using the value of ("D3") on the search page. I just put the  Sheets("PartsList").Range(Sheets("Search").Range("D3").Value).Value = in place of the cell location in an = formula to copy paste and Roberts your Aunty. Thank you to Stack Overflow for posting this question.